# How do I make Doc Changes for the Joomal API?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

I'm looking at JCache->setLifeTime(), and after having it not work as expected, and digging through things and looking at the file storage adapter, what I found is that the interval for setLifeTime() is actually minutes.

That's unexpected. I would have expected seconds myself.

How can I alter the documentation for JCache(Controller)->setLifeTime() to document that the argument is in minutes?

Comment: Are you referring to the actual Joomla Docs or the comment blocks above each function in the PHP file?

Comment: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JCache.html#method_setLifeTime

Comment: I believe this API documentation reads the comment blocks from the Github repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edit the DocBlock Header in the source code and submit a PR with your fix. (from/to the staging branch)

Here is the file you are looking for:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/cache/cache.php

Comment: I hate open source anymore. In the old days, you just posted an issue and someone fixed. The next evolution was you had to put the issue in their defect tracking system. Now you have to code the fix, and do a pull request. It's become a big giant pain.

Comment: Actually if you don't know how you can always let people know. I prefer Open source since if I make the fix it has a better chance of being accepted and included sooner than if I have to rely on a small handful of people to both consider the issue and fix it.

Comment: By the way, I've submitted the change for your issue https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/10112